# Facebook Achievements on Localhost?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, achievements

quick question - Is it possible to register facebook achievements passing in a url that is only served by my local development server (i.e. localhost)? Or do I actually have to host the app on the internet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the URLs need to be reachable by Facebook's crawler - this requirement is covered in the [achievements documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/):

> Each achievement must possess a unique URL with the appropriate Open
>   Graph protocol  tags. We will scrape the achievement’s unique
>   URL and use the information provided in the tags to generate stories
>   in news feed and on timeline. Clicking these stories will redirect to
>   the achievement’s unique URL.

Comment: thank you! <- this does seem kind of annoying though especially if the achievements system is complex